# Rackspace FIles Folder 'Alias/Redirect'

Tags: cdn, google-cloud-storage, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, rackspace-cloudfiles

I am trying to come up with a 'versioned' data system. The different groups of data I have will be updated at different intervals and are quite large (MAP TIFFS) so I'd like to avoid duplicating content as much as possible, we're talking around the 50gb mark. Say for example I have the two following categories of Maps: Country Maps & City Maps. Country Maps get updated quarterly and City maps get updated bi-annually. Over a period of 6 Months The folder structure I end up with is this:

```
RACKSPACE CONTAINER
|
|-JAN2014
|    |
|    |-Cities
|    |-Countries
|
|-APR2014
|    |
|    |-[Cities] (Not a real folder, an alias/redirect to the Jan 2014 version)
|    |-Countries
|
|-JUL2014
|    |
|    |-Cities
|    |-Countries
|
|
```

My App is given the current data version for that time period (i.e JAN2014, APR2014 or JUL2014) and will use it to form the url to fetch the map file i.e blah.rackcdn.com/JAN2014/Cities/Map.file) I would like to be able to point an alias/redirect of blah.rackcdn.com/APR2014/**Cities**/Map.file (which doesn't exists because the older cities map data is still valid) to the old folder, Hopefully that makes sense, is there any way to accomplish this? Currently I'm using Cyberduck ftp to upload my files / directory structure to rackspace.

If I am unable to achieve this with Rackspace, is this able to be done with any other file hosting services (i.e. Google Cloud storage)?

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to simulate symlinks on Rackspace Cloud Files. See this blog post on how to do this using the Cloud Files REST API: http://developer.rackspace.com/blog/simulate-symLinks-on-cloud-files.html.

Comment: Hey Hey, thanks for sending through the link, I did have a bit of a look at that page, does this work for entire folders? or just individual files?